# Smart Paypal Button gives a SameSite cookie warning in my React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

So I'm using the [Smart Paypal Button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) in my React application and I've noticed the following warning

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://paypal.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

The button is working right now but I'm worried the functionality will break in the near future. Is there anything I can do about this warning? Or is it up to Paypal to fix this server-side?

Comment: @AmarSyla it states in other StackOverflow questions that it should be broken right now since the Chrome update was in February 2020. Why is the button still working (warning instead of error) if thats the case?

Comment: there is nothing you have to do. This is a server issue and PayPal will fix it if they haven't already. Chrome still hasn't enforced this rule completely.

Comment: @Hoodlum I've added a comment to that question, because I think it's a great canonical question for this problem - but the answer is: they opted to push it back due to COVID-19. Anecdotally, I had similar "Same Site" errors, and during my testing with the Chrome flag enabled, I haven't had issues in applications I support. https://blog.chromium.org/2020/04/temporarily-rolling-back-samesite.html